# How to show 3Photos visible when hover like Google Plus Photos

Tags: css

When we mouse over on  google plus album we will see 3 images side by side , This works on ie 8 also, although ie 8 does't support css3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to a demo which may help you out:

http://youhack.me/2011/07/15/google-plus-photo-stack-animation-using-jquery-and-css3/